# Combine docs of libraries with overlapping postfix

Tags: doxygen

I want to combine the docs of two libraries: `Bar` and `MyBar`. However, this is causing strange problems with overlapping paths.

Consider this project:

```
Doxyfile
Bar/config.h
MyBar/config.h
```

with `Doxyfile`

```
INPUT = Bar MyBar
```

and `Bar/config.h`:

```cpp
/**
Lorem ipsum

\file Bar/config.h
*/

/**
Some bar lib.
*/
namespace Bar {

} // namespace Bar
```

and `MyBar/config.h`:

```cpp
/**
Lorem ipsum

\file MyBar/config.h
*/

#include <Bar/config.h>

/**
Some other library
*/
namespace MyBar {

} // namespace MyBar
```

Building with doxygen 1.9.1 gives the following warning:

```
Bar/config.h:4: warning: the name 'Bar/config.h' supplied as the argument in the \file statement matches the following input files:
   /myprojectdir/Bar/config.h
   /myprojectdir/MyBar/config.h
Please use a more specific name by including a (larger) part of the path!
```

I really don't know how to solve this: there is no larger part of the path to be specified (in relative sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the directory name in the `\file` is a potential source of problems.
When the documentation block of the file is in the file itself there are 2 solutions:

1. use the `\file` command without the name of the file
2. use the `\file` command without the directory

Personally I would go for the first solution as in case of a renaming of the file this has not to be done with the `\file` command as well.

Comment: Although this solves the example, in my production code I'm getting `/myinclude/QPot/config.h:4: warning: the name '/myinclude/QPot/config.h' supplied as the argument in the \file statement matches the following input files:
   /myinclude/QPot/config.h
Please use a more specific name by including a (larger) part of the path!`. Do you understand this? Note that I use `\file` with not argument everywhere, and that I cannot reproduce it in the minimal example.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you get 1 alternative? A bit strange, I'll have to see why this happens (small example would be appreciated, is your code propitiatory when not can I find it somewhrere?).

Comment: That was indeed why I got confused. Like a said I did not manage to get a minimal reproducer (i.e. it runs without warnings). But, my code is 100% open-source. The library that gives the warning is here https://github.com/tdegeus/GMatElastoPlasticQPot . It fails on including this library https://github.com/tdegeus/QPot . Note that is also includes https://github.com/tdegeus/GMatTensor

Comment: I just realised that I should specify that the docs "QPot" itself build without any error or warning. It is just when I build them together with "GMatElastoPlasticQPot" that the warning (or more error) occurs, it seems for files that have the same name and the are directory that share the end. E.g. for "*QPot/version.hpp"

Comment: When I understand it correctly you try to combine 3 libraries / repositories. What are the doxygen settings you use? (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x`. With a simple Doxyfile I didn't see the problems) Probably you should also have a look at the tag file possibilities i.e. `GENERATE_TAGFILE` and `TAGFILES`.

Comment: Indeed. I could also look into `TAGFILES`, but I do like the current way. Anyway, here is the output of `doxygen -x`: https://gist.github.com/tdegeus/cf46809cdd612326f7036d0020456165 (I generate the doxyfile with CMake). Also not that the error consistency occurs in the CI as well: https://github.com/tdegeus/GMatElastoPlasticQPot/pull/75 (last check on Linux)

Comment: I managed to isolate the problem: It happens due to `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH = /Users/tdegeus/opt/miniconda3/envs/test/include`, which should be allowed as still `QPot/config.h` is remaining

Comment: I tried the given Doxyfile, but I didn't get any warning regarding config.h or version.hpp

Comment: That is strange (it happens consistently in CI as well). I guess that you changed specifically `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` and `STRIP_FROM_PATH`? That question make me try, if I change `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH = /Users/tdegeus/opt/miniconda3/envs/test/include` to `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH = /Users/tdegeus/opt/miniconda3/envs/test` (so I remove the final `include`), then it works.

Comment: I didn't change the `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` contrary to try to reproduce the problem I even created all mentioned directories.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Very strange though. On my side the problem is reproducible on macOS and Linux, with the Doxyfile from the gist and with building with CMake. The only way for me to get rid of the problem is as described. Could it be to you tested with a different organisation of the libraries?

Comment: II just cloned the mentioned directories in another directory (under Cygwin) and moved the entire directory tho the indicated paths (keeping the upercase / lowercase characters as they were), so I don't really think so.